# Find the limit of this Indeterminate form

Tags: calculus, limits

> $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} [e^{-\frac{x}{\log x}}] =1$$

Do we have to apply L'Hospital Rule?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: In your question did you mean $ln$ when your wrote $log$?

Comment: It's written in the question log but I assume it's ln only!! I'm unable to attach a picture :( Need 10 rep points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tip:

> $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{e^{-\frac{x}{\log x}}} = b $$
>   $$\log{\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{e^{-\frac{x}{\log x}}}} = \log b $$
>   $$\lim \limits_{x \to 0}{\log{e^{-\frac{x}{\log x}}}} = \log b $$

Answer (score 1):

Note that this is not a [indeterminate form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indeterminate_form)!
$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}-\frac{x}{\ln(x)}=-\frac{0^+}{-\infty}=0^+.$$
Hence, by the continuity of the exponential function,
$$\lim \limits_{x \to 0} e^{-\frac{x}{\log x}} =e^0=1.$$

Comment: @B2P Note that this is not a indeterminate form!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Compute the limit $\frac{x}{\ln x}$ with L'Hopital and use that $\exp$ is continous.

Comment: Got it now, thanks mate! I was applying L'Hospital on the whole

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which $f$ and $g$ you are willing to apply it. As you wrote it, $f(x)=e^{- x/\ln x}$ and $g(x)=1$ do not satisfy the hypothesis of the theorem. Specifically, $g$ does not satisfy two of them and $f$ does not satisfy one.